# How to fix this implementaion of the Merge Sort in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, mergesort

I've read the CLRS and tried to implement the recursive merge sort algorithm . cant see what the error is but everytime i run it gives me an "Index out of bounds error "

i've been trying for 5h now

```
static public void MergeSort(int[] input, int IndexStanga, int IndexDreapta)
{
    if (IndexStanga < IndexDreapta)
    {
        int IndexMijloc = (IndexDreapta + IndexStanga) / 2;
        MergeSort(input, IndexStanga, IndexMijloc);
        MergeSort(input, IndexMijloc + 1, IndexDreapta);

        Merge(input, IndexStanga, IndexDreapta, IndexMijloc);
    }
}

static public void Merge(int[] input, int stanga, int dreapta, int mijloc)
{
    int lungDR = 0;
    int lunST = 0;
    lungDR = dreapta - mijloc;
    lunST = mijloc - stanga + 1;
    int[] valDreapta = new int[lungDR + 1];
    int[] valStanga = new int[lunST + 1];

    valDreapta[valDreapta.Length - 1] = int.MaxValue;
    valStanga[valStanga.Length - 1] = int.MaxValue;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = stanga; i <= mijloc; i++) valStanga[i] = input[i];

    for (i = 0; i < lungDR; i++) { valDreapta[i] = input[i + mijloc + 1]; }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < input.Length; k++)
    {
        if (valStanga[i] <= valDreapta[j]) //error out of bounds 
        {
            input[k] = valStanga[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            input[k] = valDreapta[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a service to all non-romanian developers on Stack Overflow, could you rename the parameters and such to english to make them a bit easier to understand, remove one layer of abstraction from the question?

Comment: It would also be nice to know the line number of the error....  although I suspect it to be where the `i` and `j` indexes are used but not used in condition statement of the for loop.

Comment: Use the debugger. It will tell you exactly where the error happens and you can inspect if all values are correct.

Comment: Sorry i've posted this question in a hurry and to be honest i didnt expect any answers ...Ty anyway guys !

Comment: The error stands at "  for (int k = 0; k < input.Length; k++) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes noted in comments below. First fix for moving data from input to valStanga. Second fix for the range on merging back to input. The parameters for merge are in an unusual order, first, last, middle. Normally the order is first, middle, last.

Comments: The program will have issues if the array to be sorted contains elements equal to max integer. It would be more efficient to do a one time allocation of a working array, rather than allocate new sub-arrays on every call to merge. The copy operations can be avoided by changing the direction of merge with each level of recursion.

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < lungDR; i++) { valDreapta[i] = input[i + mijloc + 1]; }
    for (i = 0; i < lunST; i++) { valStanga[i] = input[i + stanga]; }      // fix

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (int k = stanga; k <= dreapta; k++)                                // fix
    {
        if (valStanga[i] <= valDreapta[j])
```

Comment: @StefanAdrian - wiki article for [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation) shows a somewhat optimized top down merge sort that only does a one time allocation and a one time copy, then alternating the direction of merge for each level of recursion. A pair of mutually recursive functions would eliminate the need for the one time copy.